# UIScrollView will not scroll, even after content size set

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

My UIScrollView is a ~4500px horizontal view that the user needs to scroll horizontally through to view the content.

I have set it up as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    sview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320);
    sview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(4500, 320);
    [sview setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```

Yet the scroll view does nothing. Is there something obvious I missed? i've tried literally every tutorial on the web.

Comment: do have that as well. still not scrolling.

Comment: where do you add the subview(s) which represent the content to be scrolled?

Comment: You are adding scrollview programatically or ?

Comment: set the delegate method, unless your using xibs then the UIScrollView delegate should have been linked to the file owner....

Comment: It will scroll horizontaly

Answer (score 5):

I got similar issue. I did following modifications and the scrollView started scrolling for me:

1. Select to check the 'Bounce Horizontally' property for UIScrollView
               in xib.
2. Move the code following code to viewDidAppear instead of
               viewDidLoad:

> ```
> -(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
> {
>
>     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
>     sview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320);
>     sview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(4500, 320);
>     [sview setScrollEnabled:YES];
>
> }
> ```

I think this should help you.

Answer (score 4):

I've explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21274071/361247), but there are so many answers to this problem that suggests turning off Auto Layout. That fixes the problem but that's not really the correct solution. Here's my answer:

---

Turning Auto Layout works, but **that's not the solution**. If you really need Auto Layout, then use it, if you don't need it, turn it off. But that is not the correct fix for this solution.

`UIScrollView` works differently with other views in Auto Layout. Here is [Apple's release note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html) on Auto Layout, I've copied the interesting bit:

> Here are some notes regarding Auto Layout support for UIScrollView:
>
> - In general, Auto Layout considers the top, left, bottom, and right edges of a view to be the visible edges. That is, if you pin a view to
>     the left edge of its superview, you’re really pinning it to the
>     minimum x-value of the superview’s bounds. Changing the bounds origin
>     of the superview does not change the position of the view.
> - The UIScrollView class scrolls its content by changing the origin of its bounds. To make this work with Auto Layout, the top, left, bottom,
>     and right edges within a scroll view now mean the edges of its content
>     view.
> - The constraints on the subviews of the scroll view must result in a size to fill, which is then interpreted as the content size of the
>     scroll view. (This should not be confused with the
>     intrinsicContentSize method used for Auto Layout.) To size the scroll
>     view’s frame with Auto Layout, constraints must either be explicit
>     regarding the width and height of the scroll view, or the edges of the
>     scroll view must be tied to views outside of its subtree.
> - Note that you can make a subview of the scroll view appear to float (not scroll) over the other scrolling content by creating constraints
>     between the view and a view outside the scroll view’s subtree, such as
>     the scroll view’s superview.

Apple then goes on to show example of how to correctly use `UIScrollView` with Auto Layout.

As a general rule, one of the easiest fix is to create a constraint between the element to the bottom of the UIScrollView. So in the element that you want to be at the bottom of the UIScrollView, create this bottom space constraint:

[image]

Once again, if you do not want to use Auto Layout, then turn it off. You can then set the `contentSize` the usual way. But what you should understand is that this is an intended behaviour of Auto Layout.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to add some content to UIScrollSiew as subview for scrolling,without content on UIScrollView how can you scroll?. Here is what i did,just add UIImageView to UIScrollView as subview of size same as size of UIScrollView...

In viewDidLoad method try the following code..

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     UIScrollView *scroll=[[UIScrollView alloc] init];
     scroll.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
     UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
     imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,460);
     imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"chiranjeevi.jpeg"];
     scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(4500, 460);
     [scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
     [scroll addSubview:imageView];
     [self.view addSubview:scroll];

}
```

I tested this code it works well.I hope this code will be helpful to you..

Comment: Maybe try a solution for adding a UIScrollView to a UIViewcontroller's UIView through xib? That's the REAL issue

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are adding UISrollingView in your Xib file. This will work for you.

```
sview.delegate = self;
sview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[sview setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
sview.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
sview.clipsToBounds = YES;
sview.scrollEnabled = YES;
sview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,570);
CGPoint topOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);
[sview setContentOffset:topOffset animated:YES];
```

Also, make sure to give IBOutlet connection in your Xib file.

Comment: didnt help me sorry.... still not not able to scroll through the ENTIRE content even after setting contentsize to 3000

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same issue.I added the scroll view in xib.I also added some subviews to this scroll view. The scroll view would stop scrolling after I added the subviews. The solution for this problem was in the xib for the view in file inspector Use Autolayout was checked. I unchecked it and the scroll view scrolled after adding the subviews.

**The solution was uncheking the Use Autolayout in file inspector in xib.**