# Storyboard UIScrollView won't work

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I created an `UIScrollView` inside a `UIView` and have put a couple **labels** and **buttons** in it.

The **buttons** and **labels** go on longer than the view frame, so I put this in the viewControllers `viewDidLoad`, like so:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad  {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(321, 600);
    self.scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
}
```

I also set **Bounce Vertically** to `true`, so I can bounce the view lower, and it seems as if it's 'scrolling' but then as soon as I let go and it 'unbounces', it goes away.

Why won't my scroll view scroll and stay down?

Comment: How big is the scrollView's frame? If the scrollView's frame is larger than its contentSize, it won't scroll.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/m3QwLcN.png its set to 548

Comment: Are you using autolayout? If yes, then contentSize does nothing. You need to use layout constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you adding the labels and buttons? If you are using Storyboard and Auto Layout, you will need to set constraints.

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21274071/361247) on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should try adding this line:

```
[self.scrollView setScrollEnabled: YES];
```

Comment: added, didn't change anything